# Upgrading from apache poi's 3.2.final to 3.11 beta version giving some errors

Tags: java, excel, apache, apache-poi

I am trying to upgrade from org.apache.poi 3.2 to org.apache.poi 3.11 beta version. Doing so is issuing the following error

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project xyzxyz: Compilation failure
[ERROR] xxxx.java:[648,34] method setRegion in class xyzz cannot be applied to given types;
[ERROR] required: org.apache.poi.hssf.util.CellRangeAddress
[ERROR] found: org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress
[ERROR] reason: actual argument org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress cannot be converted to org.apache.poi.hssf.util.CellRangeAddress by method invocation conversion
```

Futhermore below is a part of the code which gives compilation error.

```
method(xyzz excelBean){
HSSFSheet workSheet = excelBean.getWorkSheet();
CellRangeAddress region = new CellRangeAddress(rownum, rownum
                + rowSpan - 1, colNum,
                (colSpan - 1 + colNum));
workSheet.addMergedRegion(region);
excelBean.setRegion(region);
}
```

What exactly is the issue and how do I fix it?

Comment: Might be me, but it appears they changed the package from org.apache.poi.hssf to org.apache.poi.ss

Comment: @Danielson I dont know . Even when I change the package to org.apache.poi.hssf I get the same error !

Comment: Can you see the entire dependency list? Perhaps different versions are used, because of third-party references?

Comment: Well in my .m2 folder there's just one version of apache poi i.e. 3.11 beta . Hence I dont think different versions are being used!

Comment: Can you post your pom.xml and a single small java file?

Comment: @Danielson Unfortunately due to security reasons I cannot provide you with my pom .

Comment: I understand... But this way I cannot locate the problem, since I think it might be related with dependencies...

Comment: Wait... Check you imports again.. So 3.11 has both .ss.util.CellRangeAddress and the deprecated hssf.util.CellRangeAddress.. Remove all ss.util references

Comment: Why are you upgrading to a 3.11 beta of all releases? Why not upgrade to the latest Apache POI stable release, currently 3.12?

Comment: Also, can you post the `import` lines for your program?

Comment: @Danielson and Gagravarr It was the problem of my eclipse as it didnt show me even compilation error. I will stop using it now !It just so unstable . Thank you all . The problem really was with the import statement. I imported the wrong class and unfortunately eclipse didnt show the compilation error at all . It was only spotted after executing one of the maven goals. How I have started loathing eclipse !

Comment: @Smrita No, don't leave us (Eclipse users). Maybe it's just the maven plugin :p

Comment: @Danielson Its definitely eclipse!